# Google Chrome not displaying Google Docs iframe without proper sign-in

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, iframe, google-docs

```
<div style="height:75%;">
    <iframe Name="RoadClosure" width='99.8%' height='775px' frameborder='0' 
       src='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub? 
       key=0AiWCyJAyHHrhdFJhMkpybF80V2dQRTZVUHF6TnAxU3c&output=html&widget=true'>
    </iframe>
 </div>
```

Google Docs Viewer does not work inside iframe (embedded mode) when the Google login session is partially signed-out (which probably occurs due to session time-out)

ONLY in Chrome & Firefox

**When I partially say signed out**

- It is when you try to go to gmail.com and get a sign-in box with your mail id and showing options like "Sign in" and "Sign out and sign in as a different user"
- This partially signed out state can probably be reached by your Google Account session timeout ... I have reached this state many times in the past ... but I have not been able to replicate this part since I analyzed the issue.

When this happens on a website it does not prompt the user to sign in it just shows up as a blank iFrame...

Any suggestions?